# How do you ensure that the user has selected at least one item in a ListView?

Tags: wpf

For a ListView how can you make it so you CAN'T deselect the selected index by holding the control button while you select any item?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the PreviewMouseButtonDown event on the ListView. In that event handler you can catch when the user ctrl-clicks and mark the event has handled. Then it won't be passed on.

As andrea pointed out they can do unselect through shortcut keys as well. Instead I think you should subscribe to the SelectionChangedEvent. You can then loop through the removed items and remark them as selected:

```
    void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            myList.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not sufficient, an item can be also selected with Ctrl+Space, a stylus or any other means.

Comment: In this case, when your event handler will be called, other handlers registered with the SelectionChanged event might have been already invoked and the logic of the application will have to suffer.

Comment: This is true you will need to be careful of that - although in practice I haven't had much problems with this. If you really want to be safe you will need to write your own List control that inherits from Microsoft's and then you can handle the events before anyone else gets a chance.

Comment: Just a thought (5 years later): Why not bind IsEnabled to IsSelected with an Inverse Boolean Converter? One shot one kill.